# TeXstudio rpm install: QT dependencies (e.g. libQtGui.so.4)

Tags: software-installation, yum, qt, scientific-linux, texstudio

I'm trying to install TeXstudio on a Scientific Linux 7.2 machine with an rpm.
My problem is, that I'm missing the following dependencies:

`# rpm -ivh texstudio-qt4-2.10.8-6.1.x86_64.rpm 
warning: texstudio-qt4-2.10.8-6.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID ea279317: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) is needed by texstudio-qt4-2.10.8-6.1.x86_64
    libQtSvg.so.4()(64bit) is needed by texstudio-qt4-2.10.8-6.1.x86_64
    libpoppler-qt4.so.4()(64bit) is needed by texstudio-qt4-2.10.8-6.1.x86_64`

I tried looking for the packages with e.g.
`yum provides "*/libQtGui.so.4()"` which results in e.g. `qt-x11-4.8.5-11.el7.i686`, but after I installed it the same dependency was still missing.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install packages of the same architecture as your TeXstudio package, *i.e.* `x86_64`; look for `qt-x11-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64` instead of `qt-x11-4.8.5-11.el7.i686`.

Comment: Thanks a lot (I'm an idiot for not noticing this)! Now I only need libpoppler-qt4.so.4()(64bit) anymore and it isn't available in my repo (at least not with this name). Do you know where I can get it?

Comment: EDIT: Found it, it was in the compat poppler. Thanks again!